# Errors when installing sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

[image]

These errors happen while I am installing sugarcrm. After finishing installing, its index.php has the same kind of error.
How can I fix it ?

Comment: it just warning message you can change the error display mode off in your php.ini file

Comment: after installing, its index displays nothing. it just displays the same kind of errors as the above image

Comment: for just testing purpose do the following thing . find the display_error and make it off display_error =off in your php.ini file

Comment: Just write error_reporting(0); in index.php  file..

Answer (score 5):

```
set display_errors = 0;
```

Determines if the errors will be printed on the webpage as part of the output or if they will remain hidden.

[check this out](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/7.8/Pro/Installation_and_Upgrade_Guide/)

Answer (score 1):

In `index.php` add following code (after starting tag of PHP)

```
error_reporting(0);
```

And Delete `cache` files.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality. (and please format your code)